# Is it possible to transfer the images from the res/drawable folder to the SQLiteDB in android?

Tags: android, drawable

I am creating an app that is fully concentrated on images. If I keep on adding the images the size of the application increases. I don't know what would be the exact size of the app but I think it might increase than 20 MB. I don't want such file size of the APK, because it is a simple and information based read only app.

So I have come up with an idea such that during the installation an SQLite DB would be created and in that the images would be stored from the drawable folder. That means the images would be transferred from the drawable to the SQLiteDB. The images in drawable folder will be deleted. This would make the app size smaller. Is this solution feasible?

Comment: It is a bad idea to store binary data like that in a SQLite DB. Consider storing the images in the internal storage or SD card and storing the paths in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the app is installed, you cannot delete files from the drawable directory.